# Drupal 7 form submit handler not executing

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, submit, validation

In my module, I create a form with a validate and submit handler.  The first field is a text input field, and the second is a file upload field.

My validate handler is getting called and exiting fine. My submit handler never executes.  I'm taken back to my form, with an error complaining that I need to enter a value in my upload field (as I set it to be required).

I am new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6, file upload fields cannot be required. You should set required = false or else you'll get this error. I think that it's the same in Drupal 7. You should write your own code in the validation handler to check if the file was uploaded.

Comment: Also, you can use **managed_file** element type instead of **file**, it'll help you get rid of all the upload management stuff.

here's the drupal documentation: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file

Comment: What is the advantage of the managed_file element?  For this form, I am taking an upload, calling file_save_upload(), getting back the fid, stuffing it in my form_state so I can process it in my submit handler.

Comment: The advantage is that you write less code and that the file is uploaded via AJAX

Comment: I'm not following you regarding AJAX.  Can you help me conceptualize the process?

I don't see an option to close the thread.